# How to drag and move UITextFields?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios5

I have it set up where i can move multiple labels. I'm having problems moving a UITextfield. I made sure that user interaction and multiple touch is enabled.

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
 CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

 if ([touch view] == tex1) {
    tex1.center = location;
```

Comment: In which class do you define this method?

Comment: I am not quite sure, but I think the problem is that UILable view does not interact with touches, therefore it passes the event up the hierarchy to the view, so in your viewController you are able to get it via touchesBegan and move the label. But a UITextView exhaust the touchEvent, meaning, for example, it pops the keyboard, so the touchEvent doesn't pass to the super. So the touchesBegan method does not get called at all in your case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to make this trick, it works for me

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *clearView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:tex1.frame];
    [clearView setTag:101];
    [self.view addSubview:clearView];
    [clearView release];
}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if ([[touch view] tag] == 101 && [touch tapCount] == 2) {
        [tex1 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if ([[touch view] tag] == 101) {
        tex1.center = location;
        [[touch view] setCenter:location];
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it to work! Is there a way to call the keyboard when I double tap textfield. I would like to tap to move and double tap to edit.

Comment: @TWcode, Yes, just check [touch tapCount] == 2, see my updated answer

Comment: Quick question! How would I add another textfield?

Comment: Each textfield has own frame, create one more tex2, create one more clearView2 (with tag = 102), and duplicate coresponding code.